# findFragmentById returns null always

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have one MainActivity and two fragments FGames and FGameDetail. I am trying to communicate between them so that when an item is clicked in the FGames it passes GameEntity to MainActivity and it updates the FGameDetail. I have separate layout created for phone and tablet.

In my MainActivity where I am controlling if the FGameDetail fragment exists in the layout update the view. but findFragmentById always returns null for both FGames and FGameDetails.

Here is my layout for Phones and Tablets

layout\activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/games_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.rao.igttest.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_fGames"
        android:name="com.example.rao.igttest.Games.View.FGames"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout-large-land\activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_fGames"
        android:name="com.example.rao.igttest.Games.View.FGames"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_fGameDetail"
        android:name="com.example.rao.igttest.Games.View.FGameDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FGames.OnGameSelectedListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //FGames fGames = new FGames();
        //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.games_container, fGames).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGameSelected(GameEntity gameEntity) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FGameDetail gameDetailFrag = (FGameDetail) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_fGameDetail);
        Fragment gameFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_fGames);
        if (gameDetailFrag == null) {
          //TODO Open a new intent
        } else {
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is in the layout (tablet layout),
            // so tell the fragment to update
            FGameDetail fGameDetail = new FGameDetail();
            fGameDetail.updateContent(gameEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Your help and suggestions is much appreciated.

EDIT

FGAMES

```
@Override
    public void initRecyclerView(List<GameEntity> gameEntities) {
        gamesAdapter = new GamesAdapter(getActivity(), gameEntities);
        rvGames.setAdapter(gamesAdapter);
        rvGames.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }
```

GamesAdapter

```
//Constructor
 public GamesAdapter(Context context, List<GameEntity> gameEntities) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = gameEntities;
        this.context = context;
    }
 @OnClick(R.id.row_container)
        void rowClick(){
            //I think as I am creating a new instance here as I dont have referencec to GamesPresenter in adapter as I am calling it directly from FGames
            GamesPresenter gamesPresenter = new GamesPresenterImpl();
            gamesPresenter.showGameDetail(data.get(getLayoutPosition()));
            Toast.makeText(context, "itemClicked " + data.get(getLayoutPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

GamesPresenterImpl

```
 @Override
    public void showGameDetail(GameEntity gameEntity) {
        GamesView gamesView = new FGames();
        gamesView.onListItemClick(gameEntity);

    }
```

FGames

```
 @Override
    public void onListItemClick(GameEntity gameEntity) {
        OnGameSelectedListener mListener = new MainActivity();
        mListener.onGameSelected(gameEntity);
    }
public interface OnGameSelectedListener{
    public void onGameSelected(GameEntity gameEntity);
}
```

MainActivity - OnGameSelected.

```
  @Override
    public void onGameSelected(GameEntity gameEntity) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FGameDetail gameDetailFrag = (FGameDetail) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_fGameDetail);
        Fragment gameFrag = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_fGames);
        if (gameDetailFrag == null) {
        } else {
            // DisplayFragment (Fragment B) is in the layout (tablet layout),
            // so tell the fragment to update
            FGameDetail fGameDetail = new FGameDetail();
            fGameDetail.updateContent(gameEntity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the fragments displayed in the moment you try to find then?

Comment: Your code initially look for  fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_fGameDetail); before the fGames, if you running on the phone where its not in the layout then you will get null (you inflated it only on large-land resource)

Comment: Hi Marcos, yes I am checking this on a tablet emulator, Nexus 10

Comment: They are displayed correctly?

Comment: Yes there is no problem in displaying, when I am phone it only displays the list and when I am on tablet landscape it displays list and detail but as the fragment is null, I am unable to update the detail fragment.

Comment: Are you sure you are not doing new MainActivity().onGameSelected()?

Comment: you are right in FGames I am doing this. @Override
    public void onListItemClick(GameEntity gameEntity) {
        OnGameSelectedListener mListener = new MainActivity();
        mListener.onGameSelected(gameEntity);
    }

Comment: Also, this line dont update the screen:             FGameDetail fGameDetail = new FGameDetail();
            fGameDetail.updateContent(gameEntity);

Comment: The update logic is in the FGameDetail

Comment: check answer, i added both solutions

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not doing new MainActivity().onGameSelected(object)?

If you using the Interactor fragment pattern, you must use the instance of the Activity you already have in the class.

Also, this line dont update the screen cause you creating a new instance of the fragment that will never be added:

```
FGameDetail fGameDetail = new FGameDetail(); 
fGameDetail.updateContent(gameEntity);
```

There is a instance already in screen so:

```
gameDetailFrag.updateContent(gameEntity);
```

Comment: I have an interface in FGames which MainActivity is implementing.   @Override
    public void onListItemClick(GameEntity gameEntity) {
        OnGameSelectedListener mListener = new MainActivity();
        mListener.onGameSelected(gameEntity);
    }

    public interface OnGameSelectedListener{
        public void onGameSelected(GameEntity gameEntity);
    } what changes do I need to do here

Comment: In FGames, call the mInterface (got from attach) method you want to

Comment: I think I am creating new instances in all the places that is the problem. can i just update my question with the flow from adapter to the main activity. could you correct the way I should be doing it please.

Comment: try to post, we see

Comment: I have updated with the flow from the time I Initialise the adapter to the click in adapter which calls the MainActivity. I am sure I am not implementing it properly

Comment: Well, you are creating everything everywhere, lets move to a chat and discuss it, soon, heading home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159780/discussion-between-brdroid-and-marcos-vasconcelos).